# Identifying the effective config file

Tags: .net

I have run into several instances recently where I have had trouble figuring which .config file a given application or DLL is referencing.  I've been able to figure it out through some trial and error, but I'm hoping there is a better way.  I'd really like to hear some suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
Console.WriteLine(config.FilePath);
```

Comment: +1, also with Trace.WriteLine(config.FilePath) and view with DebugView on any machine/app with http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

If it's running then you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (by Sysinternals, now Microsoft) to examine the file handles a process has.

Hope that helps.